# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nativePtr is null

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, android-8.0-oreo

I tried to make my own progress bar from custom view. Most of devices, included android studio simulations work OK with it. However some of devices do not, for example Nokia 8. Here is the logcat:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: com.example.example, PID: 32287
>                                                                            java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: nativePtr is null
>                                                                                at
>   libcore.util.NativeAllocationRegistry.registerNativeAllocation(NativeAllocationRegistry.java:118)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.Shader.getNativeInstance(Shader.java:162)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.Paint.getNativeInstance(Paint.java:591)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawRoundRect(BaseCanvas.java:362)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.Canvas.drawRoundRect(Canvas.java:1793)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawRoundRect(BaseCanvas.java:367)
>                                                                                at android.graphics.Canvas.drawRoundRect(Canvas.java:1780)
>                                                                                at com.example.example.views.MyProgressBar.onDraw(MyProgressBar.java:111)

at line 111 is

```
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectProgress, radius, radius, paintProgress);
```

The rectProgress and paintProgress is declared as following

```
rectProgress = new RectF();
paintProgress = new Paint();
shader = new LinearGradient(left, top, right, top, new int[]{startColor, endColor}, null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
paintProgress.setShader(shader);
```

where could the problem lies? I tried to search around but no avail.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Android Oreo. I received confirmation from one of my clients that app stopped working after his phone updated to 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the cue. After messing around with the the Shader constructor I found out that empty initialization of empty param Shader cause error when paint object setShader().

```
shader = new Shader();
paintProgress.setShader(shader)
canvas.drawRoundRect(rectProgress, radius, radius, paintProgress);
```

There was actually an if condition just before I create new LinearGradient shader that I have not included in the question. When  condition was failed so the paint object causes crashing.